# How can I get a nested attribute of each element to an array in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A rails object has following style of info. Say for example, if I do 
`res.students[0].student_id` it prints 1

The rails object is the response from other service and it is a proto.

```
"Students": [
    {
      "student_id": "1",
      "marks": 66,
      "address": 1,234 street,
      "name" : "",
    },
    {
      "student_id": "2",
      "marks": 97,
      "address": 4, 567 street,
      "name" : "",
    },
]
```

//Name will be empty in this structure

1. But, How can I get all student_id to an array in Ruby on Rails?
2. Also, how can I pass an array of student IDs to SQL query and get array of names?

Comment: Oh, so is that not an hash?

Comment: @Ursus Its not an hash.

Comment: then what data type is it?

Comment: @lacostenycoder - updated.

Comment: can you be more specific about part 2 of your question?

Comment: did you try `res.students.map{|o| o[:student_id]}` ? or `.map{|o| o.student_id}`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not asked well. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need to see evidence of your effort to solve this. Currently you gave a requirement with no code showing what you tried, so it looks like you want us to write code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assueme `res.students` is an Enumerable so why not just `.map`?

```
student_ids = res.students.map{|r| r.student_id}
```

For sql perhaps you're looking for this?

```
Student.where(id: student_ids ).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-pluck) also works on Enumerable objects if the objects within respond to `[]`. So `res.students.pluck(:student_id)` would return a list of student ids.

Comment: @lacostenycoder - I have a follow up question. After getting names with sql queries I will be assigning it to each student element. If I use an array and say for 3rd element there is no name returned the array would look like ["Mark" , "Tom", "", "Dick", "harry"] and when I assign it back , I have to exactly map it to corresponding studentId. Is map the only way? Ruby seems to have lots of shortcut one-line magic. Is there anything of that sort for this ?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I guess that was added in newer versions of Rails, do you know when?

Comment: @sofs1 I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do in your comment above. Please post a new question if you need more help on that.